# Killing insects

Tags: bugs

Are we allowed to kill insects?
I read different opinions. On the one hand they are God's creatures and on the other they can be harmful to health or property. This article takes a middle road:  https://ohr.edu/explore_judaism/ask_the_rabbi/ask_the_rabbi/4400

Is the matter still in dispute or has some kind of consensus emerged?

(It is *not* true that Noah hired an exterminator to kill all but *two* of the termites infesting the Ark.  )

Comment: My Rosh Yeshiva told me that you can kill insects if they are a pest, no problem.